# How to embed Facebook Gaming live stream chat on a page?

Tags: php, html

I wish to embed the Facebook Gaming live comments section on my own PHP page. I found that this is available at https://www.facebook.com/gaming/streamer/chat/?page={page unique id} but it doesn't work when I try to load it into an `iframe`. Tried a few ways that came to mind but none worked.

Comment: have you checked on the chrome console for any error?

Comment: None visible :(

Comment: Any help would be appreciated